# Rstudio will not load Rcmdr

Tags: r

When trying to load Rcmdr it starts loading the packages and then freezes after loading effects. I have attached a picture of the console. I am not sure what is going on, I have tried reinstalling R and Rstudio along with the packages. 
[image: console grab]

Comment: Isn't `rcmdr` a GUI? So why are you trying to load one GUI inside another GUI?

Comment: doesn't that mean it worked?

Comment: I resolved the issue. I tried opening it in R instead of Rstudio and it showed some packages that needed to be installed. Not sure why they where not installed with Rstudio though.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. R required packages `leaps` and `aplpack` to be installed. `Rcmdr` worked fine afterwards

Answer (score 0):

In order to avoid similar problems in the future, next time add `dependencies = TRUE`:

```
install.packages("package-name", dependencies = TRUE)
```